# Is adding a user to input group secure?

Tags: touchpad, input-devices, gestures

I just read a thread about enabling touchpsd gestures on linux systems using libinput-gestures
https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures
Is it safe to add a user to this group as this may allow system-wide keylogging of system by a script itself?
If not are there any safety precautions that can be undertaken for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. Change the mode to `660` for a bit more security. You can do this by creating a udev rule:

```
 sudo mkdir -p /etc/udev/rules.d
 sudo vi /etc/udev/rules.d/85-input.rules
```

and add

```
 SUBSYSTEM=="input", MODE="660"
```

This will prevent "others" to abuse the input group so if you then still have a problem related to this group and keyloggings you have bigger issues (like an exposed sudo password or a rootkit).